# Unique Pointers and Double List: problem with insertion

Tags: c++, list, smart-pointers, unique-ptr, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to implement a Templated Double Linked List, following Stroustrup's book "Principles and Practice using C++", Chapter 20.4. Instead of raw pointers, I want to use *unique pointers*.
The code is organized as follows:

- header Node.h where the struct `Node` is implemented
- header Iterator.h where the `Iterator` is implemented
- header List.h where the class `List` is implemented
- a main.cpp where the methods are tested

In particular, I'm interested for the moment in the implementation of the method `iterator insert(iterator p, const T& x)` which inserts `x` in the list after `p`. It compiles, but when I run it I can see that the insertion is performed correctly and then I got a segmentation fault, which I strongly believe it's due to the fact that I'm doing some error in using the unique pointer. Here's the implementation of the method insert

```cpp
    iterator insert(iterator position,const T& value) {
        auto newNode = new Node::Node<T>(value,position.current->next.get(), position.current);
        if (position.current == last ) {
            last.reset(newNode);
        }
    
        position.current->next.release(); 
        position.current->next.reset(newNode);
        ++_size;
        return position;
    }
```

For the sake of convenience, I write here also the other files:

Here's my Node.h

```cpp
    #ifndef Node_h
    #define Node_h
    
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <memory>  // std::unique_ptr
    #include <utility> // std::move
    
    
    
    namespace Node {
    
    
    template <typename T>
    struct Node {
        T data;
        std::unique_ptr<Node> next;
        Node* previous;
        
        Node() noexcept = default;
        explicit Node(const T& _data) : data{_data}, next{nullptr},previous{nullptr} {
            std::cout << "l-value"<<std::endl;
        }
        Node(const T& _data, Node* _next, Node* _previous): data{_data}, next{_next}, previous{_previous} {}
    
        explicit Node(T&& x) : data{std::move(x)} {
          std::cout << "r-value" << std::endl;
        }
        
        Node(T&& x, Node* _next, Node* _previous) : data{std::move(x)}, next{_next}, previous{_previous} {
          std::cout << "r-value" << std::endl;
        }
        
        explicit Node(const std::unique_ptr<Node> &x) : data{x->data} {
            if (x->next){
            next.reset(new Node{x->next});
            }
    //        if (x->previous){
    //            previous.reset(new Node{x->previous});
    //        }
        }
        
        
        
        ~Node()=default;
        
        //Move semantics, Copy semantics
        
        void printNode(){
            std::cout << "Data is: " << data <<"\n";
        }
        
     };
    
    } //end namespace

    #endif /* Node_h */
```

Then, here's the Iterator.h

```cpp
#ifndef Iterator_h
#define Iterator_h

#include "Node.h"
#include <iterator>

template <typename T >
struct __iterator {;
    using NodeT = Node::Node<T>;
    NodeT* current;
    
//public:
    using value_type = T;
    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
    using reference = value_type&;
    using pointer = value_type *;
    
    explicit __iterator(NodeT* p) : current{p} {}
    __iterator() noexcept=default;
    ~__iterator()=default;
    
    reference operator*() const noexcept{
        return current->data;
    }
    
    pointer operator->() const noexcept{
        return &**this;
    }
    
    __iterator& operator++() {
      current = current->next.get();
      return *this;
    }
    
    __iterator& operator--(){
        current=current->previous; //previous is just a raw pointer
        return *this;
    }
    
    
    
    friend bool operator==(__iterator &a, __iterator &b) {
      return a.current == b.current;
    }
    

    friend bool operator!=(__iterator &a, __iterator &b) { return !(a == b); }
};

#endif /* Iterator_h */
```

Here's the header List.h

```cpp
#include "Iterator.h"
#include <cassert>

template <typename T>
class List {
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Node::Node<T>> first;
    std::unique_ptr<Node::Node<T>> last;
    int _size;
public:
    
    
    using iterator = __iterator<T>;
    
    iterator begin(){return iterator{first.get()};}
    iterator end(){return iterator{nullptr};} //one past the last
    
    iterator go_to(const int n){
        assert(n>=0);
        int i=0;
        if (n < _size) {
            auto tmp{begin()};
            while (i<n) {
                ++tmp;
                ++i;
            }
            return tmp;
        }else{
            return iterator{nullptr};
        }
    }

    List() : first{nullptr}, last{nullptr},_size{0} {}
    ~List() noexcept = default;
    
    
    template <typename O>
    void push_front(O &&x) { // forwarding ref. not r-value

        first.reset(new Node::Node<T>{std::forward<O>(x),first.release(),nullptr});
        if (_size==0) {
            last.reset(nullptr);
        }
        
        ++_size;
    }
    
    template <typename O> //forward reference
    void push_back(O&& x){
        auto tmp = first.get();
        auto _node = new Node::Node<T>{std::forward<O>(x)};
        if (!tmp) {
            first.reset(_node);
            return;
        }

        while (tmp->next) {
            tmp = tmp->next.get();
        }
        tmp->next.reset(_node);
        ++_size;
    }
    
    
    iterator substitute(iterator p, const T& x){
        //_size must not be incremented!
        iterator tmp{p};
        if(tmp.current){
            *tmp = x;
            return tmp;
        }else{
            return iterator{nullptr};
        }

    }
    
    iterator insert(iterator position,const T& value) {
        auto newNode = new Node::Node<T>(value, position.current->next.get(), position.current);
        std::cout << position.current << std::endl;
        if (position.current == last.get() ) {
            last.reset(newNode);
        }
        
        position.current->next.release(); //otherwise: "pointer being freed was not allocated"
        position.current->next.reset(newNode); //set next of previous node to newNode
        ++_size;
        return position;
    }
    

    

    
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, List& l){
        auto itStop = l.end();
        os << "The list has " << l._size << " elements"<<"\n";
        for (auto it = l.begin(); it!=itStop; ++it) {
            os<< *it << " ";
        }
        return os;
    }
    
};
```

Finally, here's the main.cpp file with the tests:

```cpp
#include "List.h"

int main() {

    
    List<int> l{};

    int i=8;
    l.push_front(i); //l-value
    l.push_back(4); //r-value
    l.push_back(i+2); //r-value
    l.push_back(95); //r-value
    l.push_front(29); //l-value
    l.push_front(i*i); //r-value
    std::cout << "My list so far: " << l<<std::endl;

    auto p{l.go_to(3)};
    auto itt = l.substitute(p, 29);
    std::cout << "My list after substitution: \t" << l<<std::endl;

    auto pp{l.go_to(2)};
    auto it2 = l.insert(pp,98);
    std::cout << "My list after insertion: \t" << l<<std::endl;
    auto it3= l.insert(--pp,998);
    std::cout << "My list after insertion: \t" << l<<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `unique_ptr` like this. Unique pointer represent ownership and, logically, a node doesn't own either the previous or next node. You can use `shared_ptr` or use `unique_ptr` only for the next node (or previous)

Comment: Thanks. So I should change my code and let, for instance, be previous a raw pointer, right? @MichaelNastenko

Comment: @Vefhug Change both to be raw pointers. A `unique_ptr` will not be of help here I think.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Actually my goal was precisely to use `unique_ptr`. All the methods work, except for the `insert`, so I'd like not to change everything with raw pointers because I must have written something wrong just in that method

Comment: @MichaelNastenko A side question: why if just one of them, say `next`, is a `unique_ptr`, then it's fine?

Comment: @Vefhug 'Cos, in this case, you have a chain of ownership. BTW, `List::last` must be a raw pointer too

Comment: @MichaelNastenko it's clear now, thanks. Btw, is the implementation of my insert correct?  I juse edited it

Comment: I don't see the point of this. It's not the `Node` that owns `prevìous` and/or `next`, it's the `List` that owns the nodes. A lot of work for no gain I'd say.

Comment: @MichaelNastenko the fact is that I'm not sure that `release` and `reset` calls are okay

Comment: @TedLyngmo So your suggestion is to use a `unique_ptr` only in `List` and for both `first` and `last` data member?

Comment: @Vefhug `List::push_front` looks weird - first of all, it does not do push front, it resets the list to one element list. Also, it doesn't set `List::last`, so `List::insert` won't work. Also, `List::push_back` doesn't have to iterate over the whole list - you should use `List::last`. As for `release` and `reset` - seems ok, but I'd fix other issues first and checked them later.

Comment: I wouldn't use `unique_ptr` for `first` and `last` either to be able to treat all `Node*`s equally. I'd use raw pointers all the way here (which is something I rarely promote).

Comment: Okay, I got it for the push_back:  `first.reset(new Node::Node<T>{std::forward<O>(x),first.release(),nullptr});`

and of course `++_size`. I tested and it works as expected @MichaelNastenko

Comment: @Vefhug You still have to set `List::last` in `List::push_front` if the list was empty.

Comment: If, before the `push_front`, the list was empty (i.e. `_size==0`), should I set `last.reset(nullptr)` ? @MichaelNastenko

Comment: Use raw pointers, no ifs or buts. Smart pointers in a linked list will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Honestly, we implemented in our c++ course a (single) linked list using just smart pointers. I'm a bit puzzled now: why can't I write the double linked with smart pointers too?

Comment: Have you tested your linked list with 10,000,000 elements? Try it.

Comment: I see now. Thank you. Btw, I've just edited my code, using a unique_ptr for the next node, and a raw pointer for the previous one: everything works fine, except when I try to do something like 

`insert(--p,4)` where `p` is an iterator to one valid position of the list. I'm sure this is due to the fact that the previous is a raw pointer, but don't know if there's a way to fix this.

Comment: "using a unique_ptr for the next node" This will fail for long lists. The destructor will delete nodes recursively. Recursion depth is fairly limited. You need to delete the nodes in a loop, so you need a custom destructor, which defeats the purpose of having smart pointers in the first place.